# mechanize trouble with fileserve.com/login.php

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to get mechanize to login to fileserve.com I have tried the code below

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'mechanize'

    a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
      agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
    }

    a.get('http://fileserve.com/') do |home_page|
      signin_page = a.click(home_page.link_with(:text => /Login/))
      login_page = signin_page.form_with(:name => 'loginForm') do |form|
        form.loginUserName = 'foo'
        form.loginUserPassword = 'bar'
      end.submit
    end

    p a.get('http://fileserve.com/dashboard.php')
```

However it does not print out the control panel that a logged in member would see.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would try it in irb to see what you're getting at each step, make sure login_page isn't nil or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just do that. I hope, it's not too late ;)

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.fileserve.com/login.php")
form = page.form_with(:id => 'loginForm') do |form|
  form.loginUserName = "Foo"
  form.loginUserPassword = "Bar"
  form['loginFormSubmit'] = 'Login'
end.submit

p a.get('http://fileserve.com/dashboard.php')
```